# centering a everything in a div (imgs, text,.....)

Tags: html, css, center

(sorry for bad english)

I want to center everything in the div "center" (like imgs and text...) with CSS

```
<div id="123">
<div id="center">
<img>
<p>
...
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/, https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
#center{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/6gk3ztju/15/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you mean horizontal centering u can do it in 2 rules simple rules:

- Inline Element - `text-align-center` (paragrafs,headings,images)
- Block Element- `margin:0px auto;` (divs)